# Could not determine join condition on many to many association table

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a many to many association table, using this models.py and sqlalchemy

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, Boolean, DateTime, Table, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base 
Base = declarative_base()
cs_skin_case = Table('cs_skin_case', Base.metadata,
                    Column('cs_case_id', Integer, ForeignKey('cs_cases.id')),
                    Column('cs_skin_id', Integer, ForeignKey('cs_skins.id')))
class CS_SKINS(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CS_SKINS'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    cs_cases = relationship("CS_CASES", secondary = cs_skin_case, back_populates= "cs_skins")
    
class CS_CASES(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'CS_CASES'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    skins = relationship("CS_SKINS", secondary = cs_skin_case, back_populates= "cs_cases")
```

It's throwing this error

````py
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship CS_SKINS.cs_cases - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'cs_skin_case'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.```

when I try to append
```py
skin.cs_cases.append(case)
session.commit()
````

What I expected:

- A association table called `cs_skin_case`, so I can join cs_skins and cs_cases using sqlalchemy
- `skin.cs_cases.append(case)` creates a row on skins_cases mysql database, with case_id and skin_id

What I tried:

- Make a separate class for `cs_skin_case`
- Mess with `relationship()` parameters
- to make sense of Flask version of SQLAlchemy but with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name is `CS_SKINS` and `CS_CASES` so you have to use the same name in `ForeignKey('CS_SKINS.id')` and `ForeignKey('CS_CASES.id')`.

There is also another mistake in `relationship("CS_CASES", secondary = cs_skin_case, back_populates= "cs_skins")`

It has to be `relationship("CS_CASES", secondary = cs_skin_case, back_populates= "skins")`.

Comment: Could you please share why it has to be "skins" and not "cs_skins"? Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: @JoãoHenrique of course :) It has to be the same variable name that you use in the other class. You can either change the variable name in the other class such that it matches the string you enter in `back_populates` or change the string in `back_populates` so that it matches the variable name in the other class, does that clarify your question?

Comment: so in this line `skin.cs_cases.append(case)`, when I use "skin"? I'm not sure how could you tell I'm using skin anywhere else with just this little code

Comment: @JoãoHenrique the only names it has to match are the variable names where you do `relationship`, this `cs_cases = relationship("CS_CASES", secondary = cs_skin_case, back_populates= "cs_skins")` and `skins = relationship("CS_SKINS", secondary = cs_skin_case, back_populates= "cs_cases")` they have to be the same